# Server doesn't show file replacement until I open it in my file explorer

Tags: php, wordpress, file

So I am running xampp and wordpress.  I have an image uploaded to the uploads directory named `"avatar.jpeg"`.  It displays just fine.  But when I delete it and upload a new image file named `"avatar.jpeg"`, the server doesn't reflect the change and just shows the old file.  But when I open the file in Eclipse or my explorer, then the server starts showing the change and displays the new image.

This is probably something basic which I never learned about.  I tried `chmod` to set the file permissions on the new file but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

The file will be cached in your browser. To force a reload, append an arbitrary variable to your file, e.g. `<img src="yourfile.jpg?1234567" />`

Answer (score 0):

I also guess it's a caching issue like freddy K. does.

I would suggest to configure [ETags](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags) on your Server. 
Simply appending something to the URL may only help you when the appended string is changing on every update of the requested file(using the current timestamp or similar all the time will force the client to download the file on every request and slow down the page).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#fileetag